# Python attribute error when calling a function from another file

Tags: python, python-import, attributeerror

Currently I am having problems with calling functions from another file in pycharm, I originally also had this problem in visual studio. I have two files one called Main and the other Database, when I am in my Main file and import Database and run a function from database I am getting this attribute error. Database also needs to run the start function after finishing so I imported Start into the Database file and ran the function in there, when running I get this attribute error. However when removing one of these functions the program works flawlessly. This is confusing since even in intellisense it picks up the functions after being imported. Below I will post any code to help visualize the situation and post the error code, thanks for reading!
Main File:

```py
import Database as DB


def Start():
    print("\n---------------\n")
    print("1: Database\n")
    print("2: TensorFlowTest\n")
    print("3: Quit Program\n")
    print("---------------\n")

    x = int(input("What would you like to open?\n"))

    if (x == 1):
        DB.dataMain()


Start()
```

Database File:

```py
import Main as main


def dataMain():
    print("\n---------------\n")
    print("Gathering all files...")
    if (len(all_filenames) != 0):
        dataAppend()
        dataSort()
    else:
        print("No Additional Data added to database")
        dataSort()
    print("Completed\n")
    print("---------------")
    main.Start()
```

This is the code error in console:
[Error Code in console](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/303906576991780866/626467445997043792/Capture.PNG)

One last thing both files are in the same directory which is the project directory

Im sorry for such a long description, and a confusing one! but thankyou for reading and posting any suggestions to fix this problem! thankyou!

Comment: That is because of circular imports - https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/.

Do you really need to have them in separate files? Or could you merge them?

Comment: How can I get around the problem of circular imports? is there a system like the C++ linker in python I could use?

Comment: in any sort I was able to look up circular imports more and was able to find a solution that works for me. Thank you so much  @Chinni !!

Comment: Glad to know you found a solution! Would you please post an answer on how you changed your code to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I imported the function I needed where I was calling the function, seemed to fix the issue. Not sure if its the best way of going about things but it works fine for the moment.

Database Example Code:

```py
def dataMain():
    print("\n---------------\n")
    print("Gathering all files...")
    if (len(all_filenames) != 0):
        dataAppend()
        dataSort()
    else:
        print("No Additional Data added to database")
        dataSort()
    print("Completed\n")
    print("---------------")
    import Main as main
    main.Start()
```